# How to display Historical table of django-simple-history in Django admin site?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-simple-history

I have implemented Historical tracking of changes to objects in Django using django-simple-history
https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.10.0/index.html

I have mentioned a field `history` in Model using which I can query an object's history.

```
history = HistoricalRecords()
```

There us also a table created in the database with name `appname_historicalmodelname`.

I want to display this table `appname_historicalmodelname` in django admin where in we have list of records sorted by `history_time`.

As I don't have a Model class for that History table, I'm unable to use `admin.site.register(HistoricalModelName)`. How can I display this table in Django admin site?

- Django: 1.11
- Python: 2.7

Answer (score 4):

`django-simple-history` comes with `SimpleHistoryAdmin`, which bolts on a "History" button to your normal admin view that allows you to see the historical records for a particular model instance. However, if you want to be able to create a django admin view for the historical records themselves, you can do the following (assuming base model `CustomModel` in app `my_app`):

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import admin

HistoricalCustomModel = apps.get_model("my_app", "HistoricalCustomModel")

@admin.register(HistoricalCustomModel)
class HistoricalCustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```